# How to use object from Ajax request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I try to use an object receive from a Ajax request, but nothing appears. I don't see my mistake, so i'm going step by step. In this case i want to get the size value (37 in my example) from the Object (convert in json):

```
function modsdetails(server)
{
    clearTimeout(myReloadPageTimeout);
    $(".modal-body #detailsId").text("");
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : url + "/modsdetails?server=" + server,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
            var detail = parseData.size;
            fillData(detail);
        },
        error : function(e)
        {
            fillData(null);
        }
    });
    $('#modalId').modal('show');
}

function fillData(data)
{
    if(data!=null)
    {
        $(".modal-body #detailsId").text(data);
    }
    else
    {
        $(".modal-body #detailsId").text("Can Not Get Data from Server!");
    }
}
```

I have make a test with Postman to see what is the return and that is :

```
{
    "ServerModsList": [
        "areas",
        "utilities"
    ],
    "DefaultModsList": [
        "beds",
        "boats",
        "bones",
        "bucket",
        "carts"
    ],
    "unknownServerModList": [],
    "size": 37
}
```

The result is that nothing appear in my modal windows.

Thanks for your ideas/help

Comment: any errors in the console??

Comment: and is the error callback firing? If so check the arguments for more details

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Can you do  write  `console.dir(data)` right after line success: `function(data)` and share here the console result?

Comment: OK i do this now

Comment: First thing to do is to validate the response as JSON. Sounds like it might be invalid. https://jsonlint.com/ is pretty good for this.

Comment: {…}
ServerModsList: Array [ "areas", "utilities", … ]
ServerModsList: Array [ "beds", "boats", "bones", … ]
size: 37
unknownServerModList: Array []
__proto__: Object { … }
modsDetails.js:27:13
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @Moob, i do the check, and the Json is valid for JSONLint

Comment: @Corwin59 The example JSON your provided does not validate as it contains trailing commas in the first two lists.

Comment: @Moob you're right, but In fact the json is more longer and i cut to have not a lot of line, but in the original json, there's no extra coma, my bad

Comment: You need to post more code so we can recreate the problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, you should correct the JSON in your example.

Comment: So @Sanchit Patiyal, that works with direct access, but i don't understand why whithout parsing. (data.size directly)

Comment: @Corwin59 Writing in answer wait :)

Comment: @Moob i have make correction in my example, i do a mistake because i don't want to make a too too long json file, very sory for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you already specified `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery automatically parsed it as JSON, causing the  call to `JSON.parse` to fail (since the data is no longer a valid JSON string, it's a JavaScript object). You can directly access the `size` like this `data.size`. You don't have to parse it again.

Comment: In fact the json is more longer and i cut to have not a lot of line, but in the original json, there's no extra coma, my bad

Comment: @Corwin59 updated my answer :)

Comment: Very well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Sanchit Patiyal, i do a direct access with data.size, whithout use JSON.parse().

I'm not realy anderstand why that works whitout parsing.

Thanks for your all responses

Comment: @Crowin I added an answer. You can read there and accept that :)

Comment: @Sanchit Patiyal : I do it, thanks